# Build & keep file into memory and encrypt (C#, WPF, LINQ)

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq, encryption

during creating XML file I'm doing encrypt fields. It's working OK. Below is code:

Create XML class:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XmlTextWriter xWriter = new XmlTextWriter("test.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
    xWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    xWriter.WriteStartElement("root");

    testViewClassDataContext dc = new testViewClassDataContext();
    List<test_view> tvq = (from tt in dc.test_views
                           select tt).ToList();
    var propertiesTestView = typeof(test_view).GetProperties();
    var testViewValues = new List<string>();

    loopPropXML(tvq, propertiesTestView, testViewValues, xWriter);

    xWriter.WriteEndElement();
    xWriter.Close();
}

public void loopPropXML<T>(IEnumerable<T> queryResult, PropertyInfo[] properites, List<string> addedValues, XmlTextWriter xWriter)
{
    foreach (var qrl in queryResult)
    {
        var values = new List<object>();
        xWriter.WriteStartElement("tv");
        foreach (var property in properites)
        {
            Object value = property.GetValue(qrl, null);
            xWriter.WriteStartElement(property.Name.ToString());

            DESEncrypt testEncrypt = new DESEncrypt();
            string pass = "qwertyuiop";
            string encText = testEncrypt.EncryptString((value == null ? "" : value.ToString()), pass);

            xWriter.WriteString(encText);
            xWriter.WriteEndElement();
            values.Add(value);
        }
        xWriter.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

Here is encrypt code took from "microsoft academy c#":

```
static TripleDES CreateDES(string key)
{
    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    TripleDES des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    des.Key = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key));
    des.IV = new byte[des.BlockSize / 8];
    return des;
}

public string EncryptString(string plainText, string password)
{
    byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);
    MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream();
    TripleDES des = CreateDES(password);
    CryptoStream cryptStream = new CryptoStream(myStream, des.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cryptStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
    cryptStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(myStream.ToArray());
}
```

How to change it to:

**1** - first build file and keep into memory

**2** - then encrypt it

**3** - last save it.

Comment: do you mean encrypt whole xml file instead of fields?

Comment: yes: first I thnik just create xml, keep in memory (not save), then encrypt and save

Comment: then can't you implement what you just said?

Comment: I did not know how to do it, as I'm starting with c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the unencrypted values to the file:

```
public void loopPropXML<T>(IEnumerable<T> queryResult, PropertyInfo[] properites, List<string> addedValues, XmlTextWriter xWriter)
{
    foreach (var qrl in queryResult)
    {
        var values = new List<object>();
        xWriter.WriteStartElement("tv");
        foreach (var property in properites)
        {
            Object value = property.GetValue(qrl, null);
            xWriter.WriteStartElement(property.Name.ToString());
            xWriter.WriteString(value.ToString());
            xWriter.WriteEndElement();
            values.Add(value);
        }
        xWriter.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

Writing to the file using a `XmlTextWriter` actually creates and saves it so if you want to encrypt the file after you have done this you will need to read the contents of the file into memory again and then encrypt it:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    const string filename = "test.xml";
    XmlTextWriter xWriter = new XmlTextWriter(filename, Encoding.UTF8);
    xWriter.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented;
    xWriter.WriteStartElement("root");

    testViewClassDataContext dc = new testViewClassDataContext();
    List<test_view> tvq = (from tt in dc.test_views
                           select tt).ToList();
    var propertiesTestView = typeof(test_view).GetProperties();
    var testViewValues = new List<string>();

    loopPropXML(tvq, propertiesTestView, testViewValues, xWriter);

    xWriter.WriteEndElement();
    xWriter.Close();

    string unencrypted = File.ReadAllText(filename);
    DESEncrypt testEncrypt = new DESEncrypt();
    string pass = "qwertyuiop";
    string encText = testEncrypt.EncryptString(unencrypted, pass);
    File.WriteAllText(filename, encText);
}
```